# Throwing an exception on subscription in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java2

Consider the following code :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        observableTesting();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception propagated : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}


private static void observableTesting() throws Exception{
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> { throw new Exception("TEST"); })
            .subscribe(
                    next -> {},
                    error ->
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error : " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
                        throw new Exception(error);
                    }

            );}
```

I would expect this to throw an exception and to propagate it to the calling function. This doesn't seem to produce the desirable effect.

As a workaround, I currently have to assign the error and throw it at the end of the function.

Are there any better ways to convert observable errors into exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

It seem you're using `rxjava-2`. Under this version, the [specification for errors](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling) state that all not handled Throwable will be delivered through either the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` installed on the system or the error handler installed via `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler()`. If you're seeking to test the whether an observable throws or not, you can use `TestObserver` instead, as:

```
Observable
     .fromCallable(() -> { throw new Exception("TEST"); })
     .test()
     .assertSubscribed()
     .assertError(Exception.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

the behavior that you're seeing is the expected behavior. refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling) on error handling:

> An Observable typically does not throw exceptions. Instead it notifies
>   any observers that an unrecoverable error has occurred by terminating
>   the Observable sequence with an onError notification.
>
> There are some exceptions to this. For example, if the onError() call
>   itself fails, the Observable will not attempt to notify the observer
>   of this by again calling onError but will throw a RuntimeException, an
>   OnErrorFailedException, or an OnErrorNotImplementedException.

to that end, re-throwing the exception is exactly what you should do to get the result that you're instead expecting.